# Why I get inconsistent connection with MySQL Workbench and Google Cloud SQL?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, mysql-workbench, google-cloud-sql

I don't understand why I got inconsistent connection from my local MySQL Workbench to Google Cloud SQL.

Something, I can connect to my database the first time, sometimes, I need to try multiples times before getting a connection. Sadly, most of the time, it's not working.

Because I can rarely connect to the database, what kind of configuration can cause this problem?

Here's some infos:

- My application hosted on Google Compute Engine don't have any connection problem.
- My public IP (personnal computer) is added to the Authorised networks in my Google Cloud SQL instance. See: [Enabling public IP and adding an authorized address](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-ip#add)
- I have added a Firewall rules to allow port 3306 in Google Cloud VPC network
- SSL is currently disable for the testing purpose
- I followed these instructions: [How to connect to your Cloud SQL instance database with MySQL Workbench](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-tools)

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest to test your internet connection for lost packets. There are several tools to do this kind of test. Here's one example: https://www.wikihow.tech/Test-Packet-Loss-on-PC-or-Mac

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. I find out that the problem is not related with MySQL Workbench. When I test the connection to the IP and port, sometimes I received a response, sometime the server don't reply.

Comment: Then it sounds like a network problem, either on your end or on Google's end, or in the internet routing in between you and Google. I suggest using a tool like `traceroute` to see how far the routes work before they fail.

Comment: I just discovered that from where I tried to access Google Cloud, there's two possible externals IP! I just had the other one and now everything works fine! Thank you very much @BillKarwin for your help on this one. You guide me finding this discovery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the benefit of future readers, the result of the comments above was:

The problem was that the client was alternating between two possible external IP addresses. One had been authorized to access Google Cloud, and the other one had not been authorized.

Enable all client IP addresses to connect, and that should fix it.